How to Use External Configuration Files to Provide Environment-Specific Configurations in a Spring Boot Application?
Is it possible to maintain a parameterized application configurations file with configurations that are most likely to change depending on the development environment maintenance in a different file as indicated below in a Spring boot application using the maven built tool?
Sample application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

# Flyway Configuration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.user=${MYSQL_USERNAME}
spring.flyway.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
spring.flyway.schemas=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration

frontend.web.host=${FRONTEND_WEB_HOST_URL}

#links
login.URL = ${LOGIN_URL}/signin

prod.properties (new configuration maintained at the root level of the program)
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
MYSQL_HOST=178.18.10.16
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=superdb
MYSQL_USERNAME=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
LOGIN_URL=178.18.10.16

FRONTEND_WEB_HOST_URL=http://localhost:3000
REACT_APP_HOST_URL=http://localhost:8080
REACT_APP_API=/api

If this process is possible in Spring Boot, how should this application be executed via the command line and Eclipse IDE?
When attempting to execute it via console using the below-mentioned command I am getting this error.
The command used
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod
Error Indicated
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:466) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:455) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.antarctica21.backend.Antarctica21BackendApplication.main(Antarctica21BackendApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MYSQL_HOST' in value "jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:${MYSQL_PORT}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:79) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.collectProperties(OnPropertyCondition.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.determineOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:71) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:58) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.getConditionOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.lambda$getMatchOutcomes$0(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:713) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMatchOutcomes(AbstractNestedCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberMatchOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:78) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition.getMatchOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]


Try spring.config.import to specify file

What exactly do you mean with "dynamically change"? If the data in the configuration changes while the program is running it has to respond immediately? Or the config can change per startup of the software but you don't want to modify the JAR/WAR/EAR/whatever file to do that?

I want to point out that most beans (and definitely datasource beans) are singleton scoped and will be created at startup, so changing the placeholder/properties will have no effect on those beans, since those beans have long been instantiated. Please clarify what exactly you need to happen when properties change

Environment variables and property files are different thing. Fix the title.

Apologies for the confusion in my initial question. I've revised it for better clarity. What I'm trying to achieve is the use of external configuration files to store environment-specific settings, such as database credentials, that are likely to change based on the deployment environment. Specifically, I want the values defined in the prod.properties file to be referenced and used within the application.properties file in a Spring Boot application. How can this be correctly implemented?

Did you read the Spring Boot externalized configuration documentation?

To execute a Spring Boot application with environment-specific configurations, such as those defined in prod.properties, you'll need to ensure that the correct profile (prod in this case) is active and the configuration file is correctly loaded.
1. Command Line
You can use the following command to run your Spring Boot application from the command line:
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod MYSQL_HOST=178.18.10.16 MYSQL_PORT=3306 MYSQL_DATABASE=superdb MYSQL_USERNAME=root MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456 LOGIN_URL=178.18.10.16 mvn spring-boot:run

Alternatively, you can load the environment variables from your prod.properties file by sourcing it before running the Spring Boot application:
source backend-service/prod.properties
mvn spring-boot:run

Or, you can pass the prod.properties file as environment variables when running the application:
env $(cat backend-service/prod.properties | xargs) mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod

2. Eclipse IDE
In Eclipse, you can follow these steps:
Open Run Configurations:
Right-click on your project in the Project Explorer and select Run As > Run Configurations.
Set Environment Variables:
Under the Environment tab, manually add each environment variable (e.g., SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_PORT, etc.) by clicking on New... and entering the variable name and value.
Set Active Profile:
In the Arguments tab, under VM Arguments, add: -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
Run the Application
Click Apply and then Run.
3. IntelliJ IDEA
In IntelliJ IDEA, follow these steps:
Edit Configurations:
Go to Run > Edit Configurations....
Set Environment Variables:
In the Configuration section, under Environment variables, add each environment variable (e.g., SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, MYSQL_HOST, etc.). You can type them in the text box in the format KEY=VALUE separated by semicolons or click the ... button to enter them individually.
Set Active Profile:
In the VM Options field, add: -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
Run the Application
